# Configure WIFi settings with startup as a acces point

Tags: wifi

I need a way to make a RPi from scratch startup as a access point where user can connect from a PC or tablet or so. There from access a webpage where the user can setup as client WiFi connection. Anyone has such a solution?

Many WiFi devices without display works that way. For eg. sonos speaker .

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest starting here: [Setting up a Raspberry Pi as an access point in a standalone network](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/wireless/access-point.md)

> The Raspberry Pi can be used as a wireless access point, running a standalone network.

and note no screen required:

> Reboot
>
> Using a wireless device, search for networks. The network SSID you
>   specified in the hostapd configuration should now be present, and it
>   should be accessible with the specified password.

It worked for me.